# Finding value in array using pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

For a computer science class i have the following assignment.

Given a 2-dimensional array of doubles containing 128 rows, and 32 columns. The array is stored by placing the columns after eachother in the memory. Complete the following function, which returns the correct element given a pointer to the first element of the array, and some column and row value.

```
#define N_COLUMNS 32
#define N_ROWS 128
static inline double get_element(const double *A, const int row, const int column)
{...
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I don't think it's correct.

```
return *A + column * sizeof(double) + row * sizeof(double);
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you sure your teacher is not teaching C? (And even that would be taught poorly it seems.)

Comment: How is `A` a two-dimensional array if its type is `double* A`?

Comment: `* sizeof(double)` seems wrong.

Comment: Adding something after dereferencing `A` doesn't seem good, either.

Comment: @Codor Flat matrix probably.

Comment: How will the indexes be given? 0-origin? 1-origiin? Which has lower number, earlier or later columns/elements?

Answer (score 6):

To my understanding, the desired result can be obtained as follows by using pointer arithmetic, assuming zero-based indexing.

```
return *( A  + ( column * N_ROWS ) + row );
```

Here `sizeof(double)` does not need to be used, as `A` is suitably typed. Adding to it will advance `sizeof(double)` times the summand.

Answer (score 1):

try A + column_number * column_size  + row_number

remember arrays start at column 0 row 0 for ease of this calculation

Answer (score 0):

The return statement will look like

```
return *( A + column * N_ROWS  + row );
```

In fact you have a one-dimensional array that stores N`_COLUMNS * N_ROWS` elements that is split in groups of `N_ROWS` elements.

Take into account that there is no need to use the qualifier const with the parameters row and column

These function declarations

```
static inline double get_element(const double *A, const int row, const int column);
```

and

```
static inline double get_element(const double *A, int row, int column);
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.